# Why is this simple program giving me protection level issues?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, accessor

I just feel really dumb right now can you please help on why i am having protection level issues with this simple code? i even tried calling it thru object but still protection level issues.

```
class A
{
    int first, second, add;

    public void input()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first number: ");
        first = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second number: ");
        second = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void sum()
    {
        add = first + second;
    }
}

class B : A 
{       
    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You entered {0} and {1} the sum of two numbers is {3}",first,second,add); //<<<<<<<< here

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A acall = new A();
        B bcall = new B();

        acall.input();
        acall.sum();
        bcall.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's why you don't use implicit visibility.

Comment: What do you mean by "Protection Level Issue"?

Comment: like its basically highlighting the "first,second,add" in the display function and says a.second, a,first and a.add are inaccessible due to its protection level but the function is public and i didn't declare the integers as private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that stated by others that the fields are `private`, thus not accesseble from the class B. Change them to `protected`.

```
class A
{
    protected int first;
    protected int second;
    protected int add;

    public void input()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first number: ");
        first = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second number: ");
        second = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void sum()
    {
        add = first + second;
    }
}

class B : A 
{
    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You entered {0} and {1} the sum of two numbers is {3}",first,second,add); // here you go
    }
}
```

Now here you created two different classes, took the input from `acall` and then called display on the other class `bcall`, which would be empty.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B bcall = new B();
        bcall.input();
        bcall.sum();
        bcall.display();
    }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Because the default visibility for fields is "private".

You didn't explicitly specify the visibility, for "first", "second" and "add", so "first", "second", and "add" are private fields of class A, and not visible from class B.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what 'protection' issue you're talking about, but you'll get an exception at runtime in your `display` method because it's got `{3}` but you only have 3 parameters - should be `{2}`.

Plus, you're displaying `bcall` but doing the work on `acall`, so when it does print, it will print all zeroes.

**EDIT** Now I see what you're talking about, and Willem's answer addresses it.

Comment: lolyou are right its printing all zeros so how do i take integers from user in class A and then display result in class b? without getting zeros? meaning can i do the work in class a and show result in class b?

Comment: I don't know your real-world scenario, but in this example, there's no reason to have two objects. All you need is just the single `B` object: `B bcall = new B(); bcall.input(); bcall.sum(); bcall.display();`